# Python 3.3: Unable to load an image using Pygame if game folder is not in C drive

Tags: python, windows, image, python-3.x, pygame

Is there a way to pass an argument in Pygame using "pygame.image.load" without the source folder having to be in the C drive, or the scripts and images to be in the C drive?

I have tried many different things and spent much of this weekend trying to figure it out. I've searched over other stackoverflow Q&As and haven't gotten anywhere.

I have tried using "os.path.join", "os.path.normpath", and the like, and I still haven't figured it out.

Here's the code:

```
import os, pygame
load_image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('\\test', 'energy.png'))
```

And it works fine as  long as the "test" folder is located in C:\, but as soon as I move it to any other location I get the ol' pygame.error: Couldn't open \test\energy.png error.

Basically what I'm asking is: Is there anyway to get a Pygame script (specifically the pygame.image.load code) to work without having the folder, script, and images all located in C:\?

Eventually I want to make a cx_freeze app of the game I'm working on, and I want the user to be able to place the folder in any location he desires.

I'm using Python 3.3 on a Windows 7 laptop. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally! OK, I figured it out.

In addition to importing the other modules, you need to include this code to make it work and load images not located in C:\:

```
import os
from os.path import dirname, realpath, abspath
```

And here is my final code:

```
__file__ = "game_folder"    # <-- This code is needed for CX_freeze, to avoid NameError.
file_path = os.path.join(dirname(__file__), "images", "energy.png")
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Say your python script is at

```
f:/bar/game.py
```

And you have `energy.png` at

```
f:/bar/images/energy.png
```

`game.py` would then use

```
path = os.path.join("images", "energy.png")
energy = pygame.image.load(path)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not working. I've tried that. I've used os.path.join before, and I even tried it exactly the way you put it, but I still get:

pygame.error: Couldn't open images\energy.png

I double checked and made sure the folder was named "images" and that the file was in there too. It works as long as the game folder is in C:\